# Facebook graph api change and want a acess key now, how to write new URL

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I made some apps, which using fb graph to get the facebook page feed like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/Troll.Football/photos/uploaded
```

Using this URL i get all the facebook photos link, and later i downloaded that.
But last week or more exactly after 1st may facebook start to protect this feed using a acess key, they saying

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104
   }
}
```

I can generate a access token using one of my fb app from user, 
but how i use this acess token with my URL.

I mean what will be the new url to access the page photos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new url will be the same url with the the access token appended as a parameter

`https://graph.facebook.com/Troll.Football/photos/uploaded?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN`

Comment: thanks if URL is "graph.facebook.com/TrollFootballOfficial/photos?type=uploaded&limit=25" how to add access token? with a & sign?

Comment: yes that is correct. it will be `graph.facebook.com/TrollFootballOfficial/photos?type=uploaded&limit=25&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN`